# Sitecore 10 with containers error : Get https://scr.sitecore.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker

I am trying to set up Sitecore 10 with Docker and following this document

https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/developer-tools/en/set-up-the-environment.html

I have done the below steps:

1. Installed Docke`
2. Cloned Docker Examples repository on the local machine
3. Ran this command `.\init.ps1 -LicenseXmlPath C:\License\license.xml`
4. After that running `docker-compose up -d` I am getting this error `Get https://scr.sitecore.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

[image]

Comment: It's likely a proxy at your company that is causing this interference. See this answer. https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/603#issuecomment-266020709

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced a similar issue so I just switched Docker mode to `Windows mode` before it was on `Linux mode`.

Right-click on Docker and then click on `Switch to Windows containers`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This should work on Linux and Windows:

1. Download and install the publicly available certificate
2. Reboot the system after the certificate has been installed

More information:
https://support.sitecore.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB1000643